# The meaning of "= in Vim

Tags: command-line, cut-copy-paste, visual-mode, visual-block

I was solving a problem on Vimgolf (you can take a look at [this](http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/56fb2e75ccffcc0009026473)) where I stumbled upon this solution.

```
djgJ.V"=[<C-R><C-A>]<CR>pZZ
```

Could you please walk me through the meaning of this cryptic keystrokes `"=[<C-R><C-A>]<CR>p`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For context I'll go over the whole thing. First I'll describe the operations generally and then how they apply to the golf problem specifically.

**General Description**:

- `dj` : Delete with 'one line down motion' (delete current and following line)
- `gJ` : Join current and next line, adding no extra spaces
- `.` : Repeat the join
- `V` : Line-wise visual selection of the current line
- `"=` : Prepare to store something into the expression register (`=`). **Unlike other registers the expression register is populated from the command line and these two keystrokes take you there.**
- `[<C-R><C-A>]<CR>` : `Ctrl-R+Ctrl-A` grabs the WORD under the cursor and inserts it into the command line. So store into the expression register (`=`) a string that consists of the WORD surrounded by square brackets. The `<CR>` is a literal as if you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (just like `<C-R><C-A>` is as if you hit those keys).
- `p` : Overwrite the visually selected text with the contents of the register
- `ZZ` - Save and exit Vim

**Golf Problem**:

- `djgJ.` : Delete the first two lines and join the next two so you have a single line of comma-separated numbers
- `V` : Visually select the whole line
- `"=[<C-R><C-A>]<CR>` : insert into the expression register the bracketed, comma-separated list of numbers: `[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,]`. The whole line is one WORD in this case which is why it all gets pulled in.
- `p` : Overwrite the comma-separated list of numbers with all the numbers on separate lines. **The expression register is special in that when you `p`ut it its contents get *evaluated* as an expression first.** When a comma-separated list *expression* is evaluated it resolves into each element on a separate line. E.g. `[a,b,c]` evaluates to

  a
   b
   c
- `ZZ` - Save and exit Vim

Answer (score 3):

`"=` refers to the expression register, which lets you evaluate a bit of vimscript and have vim act like the result of this expression was placed into a register.   `"=`*expression*`<cr>p` is a common idiom to put the result of an expression.  It is a special case of the sequence `"ap` where `a` is a register.  The key is that this works in visual mode, replacing the existing text.

`V"=[<C-R><C-A>]<CR>p` is a clever (though obtuse) way to turn a comma-separated list into a set of lines.  Prior to pressing `<CR>` this expression looks like `[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,]` which is just a list of numbers.  When using `p` to put a register that is set to a list, vim distributes the list one entry per line.

`<C-R><C-A>` means put the WORD under the cursor into the command line, which in this case is the entire line.